# Как скролить div с помощью touchmove?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно сделать скрол для div c помощью touchmove.
Вот что сейчас сделал.

```
let lastY

element.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    let currentY = e.touches[0].clientY
    this.scrollTop += lastY-currentY
    lastY = currentY;
})
```

Вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/uyfpo0qL/3/

Проблема в том что при старте нового передвижения скролл дергается в начале.

Answer (score 0):

Решил таким образом:

```
let boxWishes = document.querySelector('.strong-content'),
    startY = 0

boxWishes.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    let touchObj = e.changedTouches[0]

    startY = parseInt(touchObj.clientY)
    e.preventDefault()
}, false)

boxWishes.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    let touchObj = e.changedTouches[0],
        dist = parseInt(touchObj.clientY) - startY

    this.scrollBy(0, -dist)
    startY = parseInt(touchObj.clientY)
    console.log(e)
    e.preventDefault()
}, false)
```